# First time developer: Best way to set up my iPhone app in order to store/fetch uploaded user generated data?

Tags: iphone

I am new to developing iPhone apps, and wanted to be sure that I am laying the correct foundation as I go about the coding process.  The app that I am developing will permit users to login, upload photos from their iPhones, write a short description for the picture, as well as view other users photos.  Where should I be storing the following data, and how should this be architect-ed?  I have heard core data, sqlite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc...  The data I need to capture and store is:
-Username
-Password
-Photos they upload
-Descriptions of the photos

Ideally, the architecture will support hundreds of thousands of user uploaded images (hypothetically).

I understand that this question is probably incredibly basic on some levels, but again, this is my first time navigating the data storage aspect of an iPhone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Username and Password, look up KeyChain.

For everything else Core Data is good. SQLite is a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Sanjay.  Here is my question, and it may be a dumb one:  can Core Data hold hundreds of thousands of images in it?  The long term vision of the app is to function very similarly to instagram - would Core Data be able to handle all of the user uploaded photos?

Comment: If each photo is a half a Meg (which is conservative), you'll quickly run out of capacity on iPhone with 100,000s images. So it'll be better to store all these images on a server. You can cache some of the images on your phone, but not all.

Comment: Ok great. This makes a lot more sense thanks to you!  Do you recommend setting up a MySQL database on a server?  Or are there other recommendations for the most optimal server set up?